# Find $[K(\alpha):K]$ given $K=\mathbb{C}(t)$ and $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)=x^n-t$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

let $t$ be variable and let $k=\mathbb{C}(t)$ be the field of rational functions in t. let $f(x)=x^n-t$ for some positive integer $n$. let $\alpha$ be a root of $f$ in some field containing $\mathbb{C}(t)$. what is degree of $K(\alpha)$ over $K$

Now first of all we have to show $f(x)=x^n-t$ is irreducible.  But how to show this as $f(x)$ is in $\mathbb{C}(t)[x]$, so the roots of $f(x)$ lies in $\mathbb{C}(t)[x]$. Then it is reducible. How to solve this problem,  any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Try to apply Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: @Mark for einstein criterion we need a prime , but here $t$ is arbitary. So how to use einstein criterion as we can't predict  $p$ dived $t$ or not.

Comment: The element $t$ is a prime element in the UFD $\mathbb{C}[t]$. So Eisenstein's criterion works here.

Comment: @Mark why $t$ is prime element in the ufd

Comment: What is $\mathbb{C}[t]$? This is just a polynomial ring in one variable over $\mathbb{C}$. Just like $\mathbb{C}[x]$, but this time we call the variable $t$. I assume you know that a polynomial ring in a single variable over a field is a UFD. (even a principal ideal domain) The element $t$ divides a polynomial $p(t)$ exactly when the constant term of $p(t)$ is $0$. So it's easy to show $t$ is prime.

Comment: @Mark Is $\mathbb{C}(t)=\mathbb{C}[t]$?. I think equality holds only when $t$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{C}$. But $\mathbb{C}(t)$ is a field of rational functions

Comment: $\mathbb{C}(t)$ is the field of fractions of $\mathbb{C}[t]$. But your polynomial belongs even to $\mathbb{C}[t][x]$. Recall that if you apply Eisenstein's criterion to a polynomial in $R[x]$ (where $R$ is a UFD) then it actually gives irreducibility over the field of fractions of $R$, not over $R$ itself. (if the polynomial is primitive then it is equivalent to irreducibility over $R$, but it doesn't matter here) So with Eisenstein's criterion you will get irreducibility over $\mathbb{C}(t)$, just as you need.

Comment: Okay Thank you very much @Mark. So by Eisenstein criterion $f$ is irreducible and $[K(\alpha):K]=n$

Comment: Yes, that's right.